# How to install "Segoe MDL2 Assets" font for new symbols in UWP?

Tags: uwp, assets, symbols

Can I add more symbols? is that I'm creating an app but standards like this list do not suffice, and I need, or would like to have more.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol

Comment: you can use fontawesome icons : https://blog.codeinside.eu/2016/03/05/using-fontawesome-in-uwp-apps/
or svg icons : http://ian.bebbs.co.uk/posts/UsingSVGInUWP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, You want to have more symbols in your app than the list you mentioned provides.

Yes, you can do that. If you want to keep using `SymbolIcon`, then you have to either set it's `Symbol` in code behind or use `x:Bind`.

**Setting the symbol in code behind:**

If your XAML looks like this:

```
<SymbolIcon x:Name="MySymbolIcon" />
```

then your code behind is:

```
MySymbolIcon.Symbol = (Symbol)0xE156;
```

**Or, using x:Bind :**

If you have a `Symbol` in you code behind like this:

```
Symbol Avatar = (Symbol)0xE156;
```

then you can `x:Bind` to it in the XAML like this:

```
<SymbolIcon Symbol="{x:Bind Avatar}" />
```

And now you may wonder, where will you find these creepy looking hex codes? Well, there's an app [Character Map UWP](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9WZDNCRDXF41) which will provide you a nice list like this:

[image]

**Or, Using FontIcon :**

You see the Codes at the bottom right corner of the image I included? There's code for `FontIcon` too. Just copy paste it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not extend the [Symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol) enumeration used by [SymbolIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbolicon) but you can use the [FontIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.fonticon).